# Quitar rutas a paginas especificas

Tags: javascript, html

Mi pregunta es si puedo quitar lo estilos de bootstrap a paginas especificas con js

es decir tengo en el index.html estas rutas

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/front-libs/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/front-libs/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.min">
```

pero para la pag de contactos no quiero que esten esas rutas porque me rompe el menu y otras cosas.

Estoy trabajando con un CMS que no deja acceder al html para quitar esas rutas para quitarlas por eso pregunto.

Gracias.

Comment: Con cual CMS trabajas y como agregas las librerias?

Comment: vtex, y la librería la agrega por defecto